# Symfony2 - Functional Testing: container not injected into a Doctrine DataFixture - Call to a member function get() on a non-object

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, phpunit, fixtures

Attempting to build a user data fixture results in

> Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in
>   ...\Tests\Repository\DataFixtures\LoadAdminUserData.php on line 35

#### line 35:

```
$discriminator = $this->container->get('pugx_user.manager.user_discriminator');
```

#### Complete fixture (w/ namespace edit)

```
 <?php

//src\Vol\VolBundle\\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadAdminUserData 

namespace Vol\VolBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\AbstractFixture;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\OrderedFixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

/**
 * Description of LoadAdminUserData
 *
 */
class LoadAdminUserData extends AbstractFixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface, ContainerAwareInterface
{

    /**
     * @var ContainerInterface
     */
    private $container;

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $discriminator = $this->container->get('pugx_user.manager.user_discriminator');
        $discriminator->setClass('Vol\VolBundle\Entity\Admin');

        $userManager = $this->container->get('pugx_user_manager');

        $admin = $userManager->createUser();

        $admin->setUsername('bborko');
        $admin->setEmail('bborko@bogus.info');
        $admin->setPlainPassword('123456');
        $admin->setEnabled(true);

        $userManager->updateUser($admin, true);

        $this->addReference('test-user', $admin);
    }

    public function getOrder()
    {
        return 3;
    }

}
```

#### Test

```
<?php

//src\Vol\VolBundle\Tests\Repository

namespace Vol\VolBundle\Tests\Repository;

use Vol\VolBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\DoctrineTestCase;

/**
 * Description of AdminUserRepositoryTest
 *
 * @author George
 */
class AdminUserRepositoryTest extends DoctrineTestCase
{
   /**
     * Set up repository test
     */
    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->loadFixturesFromDirectory($this->dir);
    }

    /**
     * Test finding all countries ordered
     */
    public function testFindAll()
    {
        $focuses = $this->getRepository()->findAll();

        $this->assertCount(1, $focuses, 'Should return 1 admin user');
    }

    /**
     * Returns repository
     *
     * @return \Vol\VolBundle\Entity\Admin
     */
    protected function getRepository()
    {
        return $this->em->getRepository('\Vol\VolBundle\Entity\Admin');
    }
}
```

#### class DoctrineTestCase

```
<?php

//src\Vol\VolBundle\Tests\Repository

namespace Vol\VolBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Purger\ORMPurger;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Executor\ORMExecutor;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Loader;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

/**
 * Class DoctrineTestCase
 *
 * This is the base class to load doctrine fixtures using the symfony configuration
 */
class DoctrineTestCase extends WebTestCase
{
    /**
     * @var \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container
     */
    protected $container;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
     */
    protected $em;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $environment = 'test';

    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $debug = true;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $entityManagerServiceId = 'doctrine.orm.entity_manager';

    protected $dir;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param string|null $name     Test name
     * @param array       $data     Test data
     * @param string      $dataName Data name
     */
    public function __construct($name = null, array $data = array(), $dataName = '')
    {
        parent::__construct($name, $data, $dataName);

        if (!static::$kernel) {
            static::$kernel = self::createKernel(array(
                'environment' => $this->environment,
                'debug'       => $this->debug
            ));
            static::$kernel->boot();
        }

        $this->container = static::$kernel->getContainer();
        $this->em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $this->dir = __DIR__;
    }

    /**
     * Executes fixtures
     *
     * @param \Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Loader $loader
     */
    protected function executeFixtures(Loader $loader)
    {
        $purger = new ORMPurger();
        $executor = new ORMExecutor($this->em, $purger);
        $executor->execute($loader->getFixtures());
    }

    /**
     * Load and execute fixtures from a directory
     *
     * @param string $directory
     */
    protected function loadFixturesFromDirectory($directory)
    {
        $loader = new Loader();
        $loader->loadFromDirectory($directory);
        $this->executeFixtures($loader);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the doctrine orm entity manager
     *
     * @return object
     */
    protected function getEntityManager()
    {
        return $this->container->get($this->entityManagerServiceId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution:**

You'll  have to pass the container to your fixture-loader inside the TestCase yourself.

Just use [`Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\DataFixtures\ContainerAwareLoader`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/DataFixtures/ContainerAwareLoader.php)  ...

... which extends [`Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Loader`](https://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/DataFixtures/Loader.php) and expects the container ...

... as constructor argument.

```
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\DataFixtures\ContainerAwareLoader;

protected function loadFixturesFromDirectory($directory)
{
    $loader = new ContainerAwareLoader($this->container);
    $loader->loadFromDirectory($directory);
    $this->executeFixtures($loader);
}
```

---

**When does symfony2 inject the container automatically?**

The FrameworkBundle injects the container into instances of `ContainerAwareInterface` being controllers or commands only.

The corresponding code can be found **[here](https://github.com/symfony/FrameworkBundle/blob/d02098a73d35eb7c48f18ffe8753d1640ba7c723/Controller/ControllerResolver.php#L78)** and **[here](https://github.com/symfony/FrameworkBundle/blob/b8f01e66ea95f2ac8e9004f6b7fb89767511c2df/Console/Application.php#L81)**.

---

**DataFixtures can be container-aware, too.**

DoctrineFixtureBundle's Command searches for (container-aware) fixtures and injects the container.

Only fixtures that conventially live in a bundle's `DataFixtures/ORM` folder are processed.

A quick look at **[the code](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineFixturesBundle/blob/master/Command/LoadDataFixturesDoctrineCommand.php#L78)** reveals it:

```
foreach ($this->getApplication()->getKernel()->getBundles() as $bundle) {
    $paths[] = $bundle->getPath().'/DataFixtures/ORM';
}
```

---

**The** `--fixtures` **flag:**

Appending the `--fixtures` flag - which can be a string or an array - to the `doctrine:fixtures:load` allows to add **additional** fixture-paths for processing.

Comment: Thanks! My reading of this is likely too simple - it suggested to me that `class LoadAdminUserData` should be moved to `Vol\VolBundle\DataFixtures\ORM`.  This apparently is not sufficient; the error remains.

Comment: That's the expected behavior because you're not loading the fixture from a command but from a test, right? I probably didn't make that clear enough. It doesn't matter where your Fixture class is stored ... you'll need to load it differently in your Test class. Please add the Test's code where you try to load the fixture to the question and i can provide a concrete example.

Comment: I have edited and added code above.  Best I can add - I'm still on the steep part of my symfony learning curve.  Your assistance in greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have updated the answer with a code-example and some explanation. *quick tip*: If people spend time to post answers that are not totally unrelated to your questions ... upvote them *immediately* to show some appreciation. People will answer your questions more likely if you do :) Every somewhat useful answer deserves an upvote in my oppinion. Which answer suits best - and should finally be the accepted one - should be chosen with care though.

Comment: Point taken re upvote.  Time difference and other obligations do not always allow for immediate response.  I accept your answer on the expectation that I can take it from here.

Comment: You shouldn't accept the answer before you've tested it. upvoting and accepting are two different things. Please report back if my code actually works for you. :)

Comment: The error has been overcome. I initially tried your solution in `AdminUserRepositoryTest` (the TestCase) to no avail.  What did work, after re-reviewing documentation, was applying the solution to the data loader `LoadAdminUserData` itself.  Again, many thanks for your assistance and apologies for my obtuseness.

Comment: PS: The reason no error was obtained was that the data fixture was never being loaded.  After seeing your reference to `LiipFunctionalTestBundle()` in another post I implemented it and eventually got complete test success.